# CoreData Parent Children one to many inverse relationships using single entity

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, one-to-many

I have a problem how to model properly in CoreData a `Person` with it's relationship to children with inverse using single entity to model.

I want to model a family, so I have created an entity `Person` for each member. A `Person` can have parents, a father and mother - for this I have created `one-to-one` relationship. `Person` can have children which is a set of `one-to-many` relationship.

I Have a problem with setting up the inverse in CoreData model as it is required for the relationships. The problem is that when I set `father`/`mother` attribute of entity `Person` to `children` it can only be set for only one of them, not for both a `father` and `mother`. Do you have a solution how to model this properly?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What about a many-to-many relationship parents-children, do you really need to separate parents into mother and father?

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple ways you can go about this.

Personally, I would just have a `parents` and a `children` property and leave it at that.

If you really want to differentiate between `mother` and `father`, you could use a single `parents`/`children` relationship and look for the `Person` with the required gender.

Another alternative is to create a `ParentRelationship` object that points to a `parent` and a `child` and describes the relationship.